# Como enviar por AJAX una tabla html y su contenido

Tags: html, c#, ajax, asp.net, mvc

Esta es mi funcion AJAX, la he usado enviando campos de un formulario y otro tipo de valores. Lo que quisiera ahora es enviar una tabla que esta en mi html con todo su contenido.

La tabla con un foreach se llena haciendo una consulta a la base de datos mostrándome una lista de items que el cliente quiere comprar, exactamente el carrito de compra.

```
    function Continuar() {
    var datos = $("#idOrderSummary");  //Este es el id de mi tabla

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlConfirmarOrden,
        success: function (result) {

            if (result == true) {
                $('#modalExitoso').modal('toggle');
            } else {
                $('#modalError').modal('toggle');
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("error");
        },

    });
}
```

Lo que deseo con esto es enviar por correo el contenido de esa tabla. Tengo esta función en el controlador donde envía el correo al usuario:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("1111112@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));
                mail.Subject = "New order";
                mail.Body = "<table border striped><thead><tr><td>Nombre</td></thead><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("111111112@gmail.com", "12345");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

En el `mail.Body` intente haciendo una consulta de tipo `list` con los items que contiene la orden de compra pero no se la manera de concatenar toda esa lista y que se muestre con la tabla en orden.

```
mail.Body = "<table border striped><thead><tr><td>Nombre</td></thead><tbody><tr><td>"+ Variable.Nombre +"</td></tr></tbody></table>";
```

Intente realizar un foreach dentro del `mail.body` pero no es posible por eso pensé en traer al controlador el contenido html de la tabla donde se muestra la orden y enviarlo en html por el `mail.body`

Comment: Hay alguna razón en particular por la cual tengas que enviar directamente la tabla? Por qué no enviar los parámetros que utilizaste para ejecutar la consulta a la base de datos al otro formulario donde necesitas mostrar la tabla? Es más sencillo y según veo en tu descripción del problema no hay datos sensibles que puedan comprometer la operación

Comment: deberias obtener los items del carro de compra por medio de una llamada ajax y generar la tabla con un foreach pero del lado cliente, entonces tendras los datos en un array en el cliene pudiendo agregar a estos nuevas compras, lo mantendrias en el storage de html5. Cuando se conforme la compra envias este array en el $.ajax, y asi evitar tener que tomarlos de la tabla html